# Why I can not Install PySide2?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I want to Install PySide 2 library But apparently this library is not found.

I tried this to install PySide2:

> pip3 install PySide2

But after executing this command, I encountered the same problem:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySide2 (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for PySide2

I used https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/ to solve my problem but I did not reach any result.

Comment: you probably need to downgrade python from 3.11 to 3.10

Comment: Did you try downgrading your python version?

Comment: @MarceloPaco       I Tried with 3.10 but it did not work

Comment: @parhamesmailzadeh I've added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python) for versions of `python 3.7+` you need to do the following to install the module:

```
pip install pyside6
```